# Infinispan 8.2.11 and Jgroups 3.6.x compatibility

Tags: infinispan, infinispan-8

I'm currently using infinispan 8.2.11.Final which depends on jgroups-3.6.7.Final. Is this version of infinispan compatible with the latest release of jgroups 3.6.x (3.6.19.Final)?

I would like to bring fixes for MERGE3 and CENTRAL_LOCK protocols into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a non-binary-compatible change in JGroups 3.6.9.Final, changing the return type of `Request.setListener()`, which means you need to recompile Infinispan.

But that's just what I noticed after a quick look, running the test suite may reveal other compatibility problems.

Comment: I found only one code compatibility issue upgrading to jgroups 3.6.19. Global.CUSTOM_LOG_FACTORY" property doesn't exist any more in the JGroupsExtension class. Fix is required also in BasePartitionHandlingTest so the unit test can pass. I can try to fix it myslef. Can you tell me is it possible to create a pull request in the infinispan project? Would it be possible for you to release new version of infinispan 8.2.x with will base on jgroups 3.6.19 ?

Comment: I'm afraid not @DanielKlosinski, we don't maintain 8.2.x any more. We could maybe go back and release a new 8.2.x version to fix a serious bug, but not to add new functionality.